# How to increase boot partition of hdd.img yocto

Tags: yocto

I created a `hdd.img` using Yocto and copied the same to pendrive using `dd` command.

On PC it is mounted as single partition "boot".

When I checked on command line using `sudo fdisk -l`, it is showing four partitions.

I booted my hardware from pendrive, now I want to remove `rootfs.img` from boot partition mounted at `/media/realroot` and copy same `rootfs.img` again to the same partition.

It is giving `No disk space` error. I am trying to copy the same rootfs.img which I deleted.

Why it is using only 700MB for boot partiton of 16GB pendrive, or how to increase boot partition size in Yocto to make use of full 16GB?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the real problem but if you are looking for a way to increase the free space on the rootfs, take a look at [IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE) as well as IMAGE_OVERHEAD_FACTOR.